# Can there be an LCG (Living Card Game) Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Can there be an LCG (Living Card Game) Tag?

With all of the LCG games (LOTR, GOT, etc.) I think there will be a lot of duplicate questions regarding the idea of this game type for each individual game

Answer (score 3):

No. LCG is a meta tag (data about data). Meta tags are detrimental to the Q&A format on SE. What purpose would an LCG tag serve?

**Cons**

- LCG is a trademarked term, only Fantasy Flight Games can USDA it without a license.
- The LCG model doesn't have a huge following.
- What questions could possibly be asked about the LCG model that would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

To add to what user1873 has said:

Adding a tag that would, by definition, encompass several games means that those games would not automatically have their game name added to the title of the page.

I think it is to our advantage that for games with more than a few questions that the game tag should be the most popular tag on the question.

However, mentioning that a game is a Living Card Game on it's wiki tooltip text here and linking to other LCG's would be a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I looked for questions marked [trading-card-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trading-card-game). At the moment, there are none.

This leads me to think that [living-card-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/living-card-game), as a tag for questions that are generally about "living" card games, would be a similarly narrow tag. Fundamentally the only generically-applicable question about LCGs that I can think of is "What does LCG mean?"